# Asp.Net radiobutton inside repeater does not work CssClass and GroupName

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, repeater

I have created repeater with radiobutton inside and binding data from db, all works good instead css and groupName.. when render - it doesn't works, user can check all radiobuttons instead one...
This is my code below, please help...

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <ul><li>  
               <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton8" 
                   runat="server" 
                   CssClass="w1" 
                   GroupName="Options" 
                   Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EvName")%>'
                   ValidationGroup="Options" /> 
            </li></ul>
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please show the associated HTML output.

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030155/radio-button-list-in-repeater-control

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I couldn't find a way that doesn't use jquery.

I was able to use this tutorial to solve my problem.
http://blog.marketnet.com/index.php/2010/03/01/overcoming-the-radio-button-repeater-bug/

Copied from the tutorial:

In the markup file, add this bit of Javascript and jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function SetUniqueRadioButton(strGroupName, current)
    {
      $("input[name$='" + strGroupName + "']").attr('checked', false);
      current.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Set up the Repeater control using a RadioButton control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMyRepeater" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoButton" GroupName="GroupName" runat="server"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Finally, in the code behind file:

```
rdoButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SetUniqueRadioButton('MyGroupName',this)");
```

Comment: Hi there, I cant code the code behind file. It doesnt find the rdoButton. Thanks